# State of the art "of" or "in" model checking

Tags: word-choice, prepositions

I am writing a B.Sc. thesis in computer science, and I'm hesitating between "in" and "of" in the following phrase:

> State of the art in model checking

Should it be:

> State of the art of model checking

I'm not sure if it is good language to use so many "of".

Answer (score 2):

It depends on what you mean

> **state of the art *in* model checking**

means, within the field of model checking, this is the *state of the art* model. In most contexts, you could use *for* here and keep the same meaning.

> **state of the art *of* model checking**

means whatever the rest of the sentence describes is the nature of the field of model checking at this moment. It is the status of the model-checking art.

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't consider 'state of the art in model checking' to be a full sentence. Assuming that you are referring to something which you consider to be 'state of the art in model checking' (let's call it 'x') it may be better to complete the sentence by saying *'x' is state of the art in model checking* or *for model checking 'x' is state of the art*.

Comment: I changed my wording to be about a "phrase". I agree it was only a part of a sentence.